# JAX-RS: Convert Response to Exception

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am using JAX-RS client to consume REST API. I didn't want to let JAX-RS throw bunch of exceptions, so I am inspecting `Response` object myself. Sometimes however, I care only about ***certain*** status codes and I would like JAX-RS to **fall back to default behavior** and throw an actual exception (that will be handled by an AOP advice). Is there a simple way of doing this?

```
public void delete(long id) {
    Response response = client.delete(id);
    Response.Status status = Response.Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus());

    if (status == Response.Status.OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (status == Response.Status.NOT_FOUND) {
        throw new TeamNotFoundException();
    }
    if (status == Response.Status.CONFLICT) {
        throw new TeamHasAssignedUsersException();
    }

    // if status was internal server error or something similar, 
    // throw whatever exception you would throw at first place
    // magic.throwException(response)
}
```

Comment: When you don't get Response object from JAX-RS API, it will throw bunch of exceptions like BadRequestException, ClientErrorException etc. But I don't like to drive my business logic with exceptions

Comment: You mean when you make a request with a TypedEntity like `client.get(Customer.class)`, then you get those exceptions, and otherwise when working directly with a `Response` - not?

Comment: Have you tried calling a `response.getEntity()` ?

Comment: Why? That returns a body, doesn't it?

Comment: I was hoping there will be an API access to some sort of exception mapper that translates status codes to appropriate exception instances.

Comment: Because I expect that to throw the same exceptions, as when requesting typed entities. As far as I know, there is no such API call, probably you should check the source code of your implementation.

Comment: What if I don't expect no entity? If it's just like HTTP DELETE and you expect 200/404 or possibly 5xx?

Comment: That is a good point. But did you try it anyway?

Comment: Accroding to my implementation (Jersey) it really does throw an exception, but in my case I can not pass typed parameter because I don't expect to have any body whatsoever. Just HTTP status code and that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support in the JAX-RS API for translating a Response to an Exception. If you check the [JerseyInvocation.convertToException()](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.java) method, you will see that in Jersey it is a simple switch that translates the `Response` status to the corresponding Exception.

So, you have two options here:

1. either you call `webTarget.get(MyEntity.class)` if you expect an entity body. Of course you can catch all [WebApplicationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) in a single catch clause, as all exceptions extend it (e.g check [BadRequestException](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html)).
2. or you make similar switch clause in your code, as jersey made.